# Passing url parameters in ssrs

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, url-parameters

I am trying to pass a parameter in ssrs and realize it should be very easy but I'm not getting anywhere with it.  When I try to do so by adding `?Agency=296` to the end of my call in my classic asp page it simply tells me that "The 'Agency' parameter is missing a value"

I have many reports I call from the page that work fine.  It's just when I try to pass a parameter that it doesn't work.  Within the report I have the parameter set up and hidden. I've also tried it as Internal but it still breaks.

My call to the ssrs is: https://testserver.adomain.net/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fname%2fReports%2fIYSANew%2frptBilling&rs:Command=Render&Agency=296

Note: I've substituted my `testserver.adomain.net` and 'name' in this post but have the correct ones in the call.

If I have the parameter visible and input when the report comes up it works fine.

I really appreciate any and all help I get with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **ReportViewer.aspx** instead of Report.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer Anup.  Now I get the following: Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid values for all parameters. (rsParameterError)

Comment: When I use ReportViewer I get the following error:
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Reports/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx

Comment: Did you **test your URL in browser** or just in the asp app?. Can you please show us the updated URL as it will be easier for troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Anup - right now I have a request in to my provider to see if it's on their end.  I should be able to simply put a shortened version of my URL (http:// (servername)/ReportServer/) but when I put it in (with my correct servername) it gives me the error report.  So, something's going on.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to think about when calling the report web service via URL:

1. DO YOU HAVE ACCESS by your user or automated code to that location?  If you cannot get to the url of

   ```
   http:// (servername)/ReportServer/(pathtoreport)
   ```

   without parameters then there is an issue with permissions.
2. Ensure your label of the parameter is the same as the actual name of the parameter and ensure you can pass in the correct string, int, or datatime you expect.  It should be appending:

   ```
   & + (ParameterName) + =(value)
   ```

   I know this works as I just did it on my Dev Server with a parameter called 'Test' that accepts a 'Text' value with:

   ```
   http:// ru___:81/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTest%2fTest&rs:Command=Render&Test=abc
   ```

You need to try the URL method directly in a browser if you are not already before attempting to do the calls in code on a page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer djangojazz.  Yes - to my eye it should work.  (servername) and path are fine.  I have done this a thousand times and it works.  It's the parameter that is giving me the problem.  I did just change it to ReportViewer.aspx per another suggestion but that just changed the error.  Everything else seems fine.  My parameter name is Agency.  I've put it in the URL as that.  I am calling it from a classic asp page.  It's really strange.

Comment: I think you're right.  I have access to the report server using Report.aspx but not using ReportServer.aspx.  I will ask my provider for answers.  Thank you djangojazz

Comment: No problem, 9 out of 10 SSRS problems people have, deal with security in my experience.